# Due to "repository has no Release file" errors, apt-get update failed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

This is the output I'm getting from `apt-get update`:

[image: apt-get update command output]

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is as below

[image: my sources.list file]

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/883731) on the question ["How do I restore the default repositories?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question but did you use "sudo apt-get update" or just "apt-get update"? It might be a permission issue if you didn't.

Comment: @MichaelKnoll it's a `root` shell, also the error output for root privileges is different, it is not an absent sudo issue

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and let me know the outcome.

1. go to `cd /etc/apt`
2. cp sources.list sources.list.bk
3. vi sources.list and delete everything.
   add the following:

> ```
> #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted
> # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
> # newer versions of the distribution.
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
> ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
> ## distribution.
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
> ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
> ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
> ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
> ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
> ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
> ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
> ## security team.
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
> ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
> ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
> ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
> ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
> ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> # deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
> ## 'partner' repository.
> ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
> ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
> # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
> # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
> # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
> # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
> # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
> ```

SAVE.

retry to apt update

post here the output.